# How to Enqueue Core WordPress Jquery into Class

Tags: wordpress, class, jquery-ui, plugins, enqueue

What is the proper way to enqueue into a class? It seems fine to use just

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
```

Into a theme template but if you use the same line inside the enqueue_scripts boilerplate class area it does not work.

I can get custom JS to enqueue in fine with this

```
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/tagmanager-master/tagmanager.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
```

But can't seem to get the right line for something that comes in WordPress is not on by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a custom file/version of tabs directly into the plugin because with tabs activated with:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tabs-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../js/tabs.js', array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-accordion', 'jquery-ui-tabs') );
```

Not sure why but:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
```

Was loading but it was not making tabs work.

Answer (score 0):

define jquery-ui-tabs as $deps your custom js file:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/tagmanager-master/tagmanager.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-tabs' ), $this->version, false );
```